# Copying data from multiple table to single table in realtime

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have 10 tables, each with 3 columns shown below.

```sql
create table table_1
(
    signal_id text not null,
    signal_timestamp text not null,
    value numeric not null 
);
```

And I have a source application inserting 50 rows per second into each table, continuously. I aim to collect them all in a single table

```sql
create table table_all_signals 
(
    source_id int not null,
    signal_id text not null,
    signal_timestamp text not null,
    value numeric not null 
);
```

Above `source_id` should be unique for each table, e.g. `source_id` is `1` for `table_1`, `2` for `table_2` and so on. Every new row inserted into any table should be copied to `table_all_signals` with respective `source_id`. I can't use a `view` because I want to broadcast a `NOTIFY` from a trigger on this table to `LISTEN` in my python client for new rows. I think we cannot create triggers on views.

```sql
begin;
alter table table_1 rename to table_1_legacy;
create view table_1 as 
  select signal_id as "signalID", 
         signal_timestamp as "timestamp",
         value as "value"
  from table_all_signals
  where source_id=1;

create or replace rule table_1_singal_id_i as on insert to table_1
  do instead 
  insert into table_all_signals select 1::int,new.* 
  returning signal_id as "signalID", 
            signal_timestamp as "timestamp",
            value as "value";

create or replace rule table_1_signal_id_u as on update to table_1
  do instead 
  update table_all_signals
  set signal_id=new."signalID",signal_timestamp=new."timestamp",value=new."value"
  where source_id=1 and signal_id=old."signalID" and signal_timestamp=old."timestamp" and value=old."value"
  returning signal_id as "signalID", 
            signal_timestamp as "timestamp",
            value as "value";

create rule table_1_signal_id_d as on delete to table_1
  do instead 
  delete from table_all_signals
  where source_id=1 and signal_id=old."signalID" and signal_timestamp=old."timestamp" and value=old."value"
  returning signal_id as "signalID", 
            signal_timestamp as "timestamp",
            value as "value";
commit;
```

I did the above for the other 9 tables as well

```sql
insert into table_all_signals select 1,* from table_1_legacy;
insert into table_all_signals select 2,* from table_2_legacy;
--...
insert into table_all_signals select 10,* from table_10_legacy;
```

I have executed above query first, Then executed below query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_all_signals
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
LIMIT 10000
```

I am able to see rows from all tables with respective `source_id`. It is okay so far.

Now again I have executed below query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_all_signals
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
LIMIT 10000
```

Now I am also getting same rows I got from previous query. My expectation is I should get newly inserted rows. I have queried all 10 tables, they are getting inserted with new rows regularly. But those rows are not getting copied to `table_all_signals` automatically.

To update `table_all_signals` with latest rows, I have to execute below query every time.

```sql
insert into table_all_signals select 1,* from table_1_legacy;
insert into table_all_signals select 2,* from table_2_legacy;
---...
insert into table_all_signals select 10,* from table_10_legacy;
```

Is there any solution to make `table_all_signals` get updated automatically (without running above query) when any of the 10 source tables gets new rows?

Comment: If you want automatic updates, would you consider a view instead of a table?
```create view <view_name> as select columns from tbl1 union all select columns from tbl2``` and so on. So you can avoid writing your procedure/trigger etc

Comment: I cann't use view. Because I want to create NOTIFY/LISTEN on table to inform my python client regarding new row. I think We cannot create NOTIFY/LISTEN on VIEWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely feeding your rows into the `_legacy` tables. Source devices should still be configured to write into `table_1`, `table_2`,...`table_N` like they did before, and now the rules should redirect them to the common `table_all_signals`.

If that's a problem, you can skip hiding the `table_N` behind views and set up the rules directly on them: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pj3EPi9h)

```sql
begin;
create rule table_1_singal_id_i as on insert to table_1
  do instead 
  insert into table_all_signals select 1::int,new.* 
  returning signal_id as "signalID", 
            signal_timestamp as "timestamp",
            value as "value";
create rule table_1_singal_id_u as on update to table_1
  do instead 
  update table_all_signals
  set signal_id=new."signalID", 
      signal_timestamp=new."timestamp",
      value=new."value"
  where source_id=1
  and signal_id=old."signalID"
  and signal_timestamp=old."timestamp"
  and value=old."value"
  returning signal_id as "signalID", 
            signal_timestamp as "timestamp",
            value as "value";
create rule table_1_singal_id_d as on delete to table_1
  do instead 
  delete from table_all_signals
  where source_id=1
  and signal_id=old."signalID"
  and signal_timestamp=old."timestamp"
  and value=old."value"
  returning signal_id as "signalID", 
            signal_timestamp as "timestamp",
            value as "value";
commit;
insert into table_all_signals select 1,* from table_1;
```

Instead of inserting into `table_1` this will now get redirected to `table_all_signals`:

```sql
insert into table_1 
  select gen_random_uuid(),
         '2023-11-21 12:46:49.734534'::timestamp-'100 microseconds'::interval*random(),
         round((random()*1e3)::numeric,6) 
  returning *;
```

| signalID | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2a8a9cc5-23cb-423f-9a06-215bc90d3e16 | 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734502 | 123.257321 |

The row didn't go to `table_1`:

```sql
select * from table_1;
```

| signalID | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

The row went to `table_all_signals` instead

```sql
select * from table_all_signals;
```

| source_id | signal_id | signal_timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2a8a9cc5-23cb-423f-9a06-215bc90d3e16 | 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734502 | 123.257321 |

Comment: I am getting error like "ERROR:  cannot create a RETURNING list for a relation containing dropped columns 

SQL state: 0A000" after executing the first block i.e. between begin; and commit;

Comment: I got it now. There was a datatype mismatch between table_1 and table_all_signals. Thank You