# PostgreSQL: is it possible to perform insert into multiple tables based on select function?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Suppose I have a complex PostgreSQL function designed to aggregate and report data from several related tables in a database. For example it can look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.aggregate_sales_data(
    sales_rep_id integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(product_id integer, customer_id integer, total_sales_amount numeric, last_sale_date timestamp with time zone, region_id smallint) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.product_id) s.product_id, c.customer_id, SUM(s.amount) as total_sales_amount, MAX(s.sale_date) as last_sale_date, MAX(s.region_id) as region_id
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN customers c ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE s.sale_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 month' AND s.sales_rep_id = sales_rep_id
GROUP BY s.product_id, c.customer_id
ORDER BY s.product_id, c.customer_id ASC
LIMIT 500;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Now I want this function to return additional row.

Lets say
`(2, 2, 3, NOW(), 1)`.

Can I perform insert using this function without making manual inserts into tables customers and sales?

In this specific case it might not be hard but sometimes the function can have multiple joints and its a pretty tedious work to do that.
Usually I need to do that for testing, maybe there's an another approach I am missing?

Possible solution is to use a hardcoded union inside of the function, but I prefer a more 'correct' approach if there is one.

**UPDATE**

Let's say we do this:

```sql
insert_customers_and_products(123, 456, 100.00, '2024-03-06 10:00:00', 1);
```

We get this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_id = 456;
```

Returns `(456, null)`

```sql
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = 123;
```

Returns `(123, 100, '2024-03-06 10:00:00', 1, null, null, null)`

```sql
SELECT * FROM aggregate_sales_data() 
WHERE product_id = 123 AND customer_id = 456;
```

Returns `(123, 456, 100.00, '2024-03-06 10:00:00', 1)`

What should be in `insert_customers_and_products`? Can we make it without handwriting `insert`s for each table? `Union` would give us the last `select`, but is it possible to achieve all three of them using the initial function somehow?

Comment: If you just want to strap an additional, custom row to any output, append `union all select 2, 2, 3, NOW(), 1` to your query. If you mean to flip this function from selecting rows to editing rows that it normally returns, you can ask it to return PK column/`ctid` from `sales`/`customers` in each row, then use those to target the origin record in each table.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I added a more clear example of what I want to achieve. Indeed the PK column would help to make updates - good to know, but here I want to make just inserts.

Comment: You can't have a multi-table `insert`, and if you set up a single, multi-table `view`, it won't be *updatable* (can't be the target of an `update`/`insert`/`delete`). If you want it all in one statement, you can run the inserts in `with` CTEs, or just run them separately in the function/procedure. Either way, they are always separate in some way.

Comment: That's pretty much it, if that's just a syntactic question. If you were in desperate need of an insertable multi-table view, you'd create a table that follows the ouput structure of this function, set up a `trigger` on that table and let the trigger split the incoming rows and redirect them to the corresponding tables. But that's doing the same thing you could do right in the `insert_customers_and_products`, just elsewhere, only semi-useful if you were dealing with some stubborn source of records that insisted on feeding you denormalised data, into a table, that you'd want to hijack and split.

Comment: It's also possible using the [rule system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html), but that's typically dirty and prone to errors. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77569208/5298879)'s an example of that, but to redirect rows flowing into multiple tables into one common table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with clause in postgresql which helps to create a temporary table.it drop the table at the end of the session.
Refer this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Comment: It's only colloquially a *temp table* and it lives on only until the end of the statement, not the transaction and definitely not the session. Still, your key point stands: OP's `select` can be wrapped in a CTE, a subquery or dumped into a temp table, then used to feed the `insert`/`update`.

Comment: I was hoping there is a simpler solution, but I think `WITH` does make it easier. Still would need to go over all of the tables, but at least not writing two inserts. It might actually save a lot of time when there's more than two tables. Thanks! 
Here's an example for my use case.

`WITH new_customer AS (
    INSERT INTO customers (name, region_id)
    VALUES ('Sarah', 1)
    RETURNING customer_id
)
INSERT INTO sales (product_id, customer_id, amount, sale_date, sales_rep_id, region_id)
VALUES (7, (SELECT customer_id FROM new_customer), 30000.50, '2025-03-07 12:30:00', 1, 10);`